# Can I get output from Powershell script and save it in a variable in Terraform?

Tags: powershell, terraform

I am calling a powershell script from terraform. I want powershell script to return a value and terraform has to receive it in a variable. Can this be posible?
Terraform script:

```
resource "null_resource" "example26" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
   
  command = "powershell.exe -file ./sample.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
  }
}
```

Powershell script:

```
    Get-AzIotHubDeviceConnectionString -ResourceGroupName "IOTrg" -IotHubName "myiothub143mnj" 
     -DeviceId "myDevice1" -KeyType primary
```

any suggestions is welcomed

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Unless you are planning to pass the variable value using the command line.

Comment: thank you for the response. If that is not possible, can we get the output  from the powershell script to a file or a storage, from terraform?

Comment: You can, e.g., if there is a way to redirect the output from a shell script to a file, then yes.

Comment: yes, i could pass the output to a file. thank you